# Identify unknown TI controller

Tags: hardware

Can anyone ID this TI chip? Looks like some sort of controller (in a older toy keyboard). there is only one other chip on the PCB (the audio amplifier). Quick googling ended on a dead end since the numbers itself dont give usable results
[image: unknown Chip on PCB]